# How to create a private API on an elastic beanstalk NodeJS app that only lambdas can access

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, networking, aws-lambda

I have a pre-existing NodeJS server running on Elastic Beanstalk with some public APIs exposed using Express.

I want to create an additional private API (on the same server) that can only be used by lambda functions.

What's the best way of doing this? If I access the private API using its public route (e.g. `my-app.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`) will I be able to control access at the Express level using networking? Or is there some way I can make requests to this app without using the wider internet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create  functions for the extended api in lambda and call them from your existing node.js app running on elastic beanstalk using AWS-SDK.

P.S :you can attach a role that have permissions to invoke lambda functions to the beanstalk application.

Comment: Problem with this is I would have to give these new lambdas database access. My existing EB service manages communication with the database, and my understanding of microservice best practices is to avoid giving multiple services access to the same database, to avoid consistency/connection issues.

Comment: So you need ACL kind of thing to control access to your private API which can be accessed by lambda only.